# How to use URL path as a file name to download?

Tags: qt, url, download

I want to download these 2 **app.zip** files from a server:

https://tempapps.myserver.com/apps%2FNews%2Fapp.zip

https://tempapps.myserver.com/apps%2Fsports%2Fapp.zip

When I download these files with mozilla, it downloads them as **apps_news_app.zip** and **apps_sports_app.zip**.
I want to achieve the same in my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get normal-human readable url from percent-encoded one:

```
QString humanReadable = QUrl::fromPercentEncoded("https://example.com/something%20here.zip");
```

To get percent-encoded url:

```
QUrl myUrl("https://example.com/something here.zip");
QString percentEncoded = myUrl.encoded();
```

For more information, be sure to visit the [QUrl documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html).

Answer (score 3):

If using java, you would use something like

```
String newUrl = "whatever the url is".replace("\%2F", "_");
```

Open http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html and scroll to **replace** for info.

BTW, I am not sure about the backslash. If the above doesn't work, try different combinations of backslash or not before those argument strings.

Comment: These kind of requests for clarifications need to go as comments to the original question.

Comment: Ya know it but what to do in case of other percent code in the url. Is there a way to handle them generally ?

Comment: @Ravi, His question is, where can he find a table about which %symbol to replace with which symbol, Like what he should do in the case of %2E and others? +1 for anwer.

Comment: @Sunny, Ooh... BTW Ravi's comment was from before I edited answer. Anyway, maybe there's some kind of char constants or somefing.

Comment: Answer is too specific, it can only handle one escaped symbol :(